# Accessing WMS with Basic Authentication?

Tags: wms, arcgis-pro, authentication

I am trying to access a Basic-Auth secured WMS Service. When requesting the Capabilities document, the service will always list *some* layers, even without authentication. But *with* authentications, more layers should be listed.

Unfortunately it won't work, only publicly available layers are listed in ArcGIS Pro. When I look at the HTTP request I can not see an Authorization header.

What kind of authentication is used in ArcGIS Pro (or ESRI products in general) when adding username/password in the "Add WMS Server Connection" Dialog? How is this intended to work?

I am completely in control of said service, it is possible to debug and configure any way we like. At the moment it supports HTTP Basic *only* but other methods could be implemented. I tested this service with a Browser and QGIS, where everything works as expected.

Comment: Can you test using an authkey in the WMS URL?

Comment: While that probably would work, it is not secure at all. I hope we don't have to resort to that, since all GIS clients should support Basic Auth, no?

Comment: Just another test to cover all bases. Check out [PolyGeo's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254029/add-secured-wms-service-from-geoserver-to-arcgis-10-2-to-10-4) to a similar question.

Comment: Thanks for the link. We tried contacting ESRI before, but this lead to no satisfying answer. What I'm trying to find out is this: _How is it actually supposed to work with ArcGIS_? I don't get any errors, nor can I see any HTTP Headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike QGIS for example, ArcGIS Pro won't just happily send user credentials in the initial Request. It tries without Authorization header first, expects a `401 Unauthorized` Status and a `WWW-Authenticate Basic` Header in return. Then, and only then, the Authorization header with user credentials will be set. This is per the [Spec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), but happens to be a bit inconvenient.

In our case, we always want to answer with a Capabilities document, because we need authentication only for *some* layers. An unauthorized user will therefore just get a much shorter list of layers. An additional mechanism for distinguishing users is needed, I opted for an additional HTTP GET parameter in the URL.